# Monitoring a set of directories and generating "events", when new files appear - can libevent or libev do that?

Tags: php, unix, libevent, libev

I'm writing a program in PHP (don't ask), which needs to monitor a set of directories waiting for files to appear and processing newcomers.

Can libevent or libev (both have matching PHP-extensions) generate such events? I know, the underlying mechanisms used by both (kqueue, epoll, etc.) support this, but do the libraries take advantage of the functionality?

My program has to work on Linux AND Solaris, so straightforward use of inotify is out...

Thanks!

Comment: You can try using the `watch` command.

Comment: threes always a cron job

Comment: Really, Dagon? A cron job? And how often would you run it? Every minute? Initializing an entire php process for nothing (most of the time) and delaying the processing of the submitted file by an average of 30 seconds? Awesome idea...

Comment: i run numerous cron jobs every minute, if that uses to many resources your on a very underpowered server.

Comment: I suppose, you drive an 18-wheeler to work every day too. Just in case...

Answer (score 0):

You can use libfam to get fam to report events on files and directories, and use libev or libevent to watch the sockets yourself (including the socket you get to the FAM daemon).

Comment: Because I'd be using two different event-sources (FAM and libev(ent)), I'd need two different threads waiting on each source... Unfortunately, creating a multi-threaded application in PHP is rather difficult :-(

Answer (score -1):

No, you won't be able to do it using libevent or libev, you need to use something like inotify/dnotify. You can however watch file descriptors obtained with inotify with libevent or libev.

Comment: Thanks, Remi, but -- as I point out in the question itself -- the program has to work on both Linux and Solaris, so straightforward use of inotify is out.

FAM (Gamin) seems to be doing it for me for the time being -- watching directories nicely. Unfortunately, that's the _only_ thing it can do -- monitoring sockets, for example, is not on its list of capabilities...